# Can content provider use singleton before onCreate() is called

Tags: java, android

Hi I reference a singleton in my ContentProvider in below way, but I occasionally get ANR for it. Anyone know why it cause ANR? Is it because installProvider happened before app onCreate() ?

```
Class CustomizedContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
   private SingletonA a = SingletonA.getInstance();

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      a.toSomething();
   } 

}

Class SingletonA {
   public static SingletonA getInstance() {
       return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using singletons is fine.  However, it's how you use them that may cause problems.

Your ContentProvider's [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#ContentProvider()) and [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#onCreate()) method are both called from the main thread.

Whenever you execute code on the main thread, you need to ensure it executes quickly or is [moved to a background thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading).  Android allows approximately 5 seconds of execution time on the main thread before it will raise an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).

Your variable `a` is initialized during construction, and your singleton's `toSomething` method is called during onCreate.

So it's hard to tell what about your SingletonA is responsible for the ANR.  It could be something to do with the work it does when it is created, or it could be something to do with the work it does when `toSomething` is called, or both.

You could perform [method profiling](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) on your app to help you determine what is taking so long to execute.  Or, for a simple check, you could grab the system time at the beginning and at the end of your constructor, and at the beginning and end of your onCreate method and get the time deltas to get an idea of what to look at next.